# Maximum Recursion Depth

Tags: code-golf

Does your language have a maximum recursion depth (MRD)?

Let's say your language has **MRD=500**

Write a code that finds the recursion depth and outputs the **exact value**

For the case above your program (or function) should output **500**

**Code-Golf**
Shortest answer wins!

Comment: Could you please verify whether hardcoding the output if you know it is allowed or not?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing  ..."that finds the recursion depth" means hardcoding is invalid

Comment: May we take an input of 0 (the "empty" integer input)? I actually don't think (really, know) if verbs in J can be executed without an input.

Comment: @cole Yes, if it is the only way..

Comment: I think the main problem with this challenge is that printing a hardcoded value is not allowed, but reading a hardcoded system variable is fine. The two don't really seem significantly different to me.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem built-ins many times use hardcoded information. This challenge allows built-ins.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. They're both simply reading a hardcoded value, but one is allowed and the other isn't.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem built-in in mathematica can also have the swiss flag (I have seen this challenge here), but posting the same flag as jpg is invalid.

Comment: What about languages that have call stack overflows (e.g. Java), but no hard recursion limit (in java, the number of times a function can call itself before error changes depending on available stack memory and other stuff). I could write a function that output how many times the function executed, but it wouldn't be a consistent value...

Comment: ...And if the language *doesn't* have an inherent maximum recursion depth (for example, because it is dependent on the size of the stack, and thus highly variable depending on runtime circumstances)? Does that make it ineligible for this competition?

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix if that's the case, just output the current MRD

Comment: @CodyGray just choose another language which CAN compete

Comment: If it's valid to output the "current" max recursion depth, is it valid to modify the max recursion depth and then output the new value?

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_limit_of_recursion

Comment: is a recursive function that runs forever due to tail-call optimization a valid submission?

Comment: Your comment to Cody Gray misses the point: it's not clear whether such languages can compete, and if so what they should output. Rather than answering the question as though they already know the answer, you should edit the challenge to be explicit about all the tricky cases.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## Mathematica, 15 bytes

```
$RecursionLimit
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfJSg1ubSoODM/zyczN7Pkf0BRZl6JgkMa1///AA)

Comment: Of course Mathematica has a built in for this! +1

Comment: Gotta love Mathematica +1

Comment: Emacs Lisp in the same vein (19): max-lisp-eval-depth

Answer (score 21):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 40 bytes

```python
def f(x=2):
 try:f(x+1)
 except:print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNo8LWSNOKS6GkqNIKyNE21ORSSK1ITi0osSooyswr0ajQ/J@mofkfAA)

Without just reading it from the builtin. We start at 2 instead of 1 because the except clause is run one level before it errors. This is a byte shorter in python 2, of course.

Answer (score 15):

## [JavaScript (Babel)](https://babeljs.io/), <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```js
f=_=>do{try{-~f()}catch(e){}}
```

- 2 bytes saved thanks to Neil.

[Try it here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbjgFwCgAzAXgH0SA-AExAG89UBPOgWgD8isBfYZPYAAt0sTHW7cCoSDATQQAc3RdMmIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=), or use the Snippet below to test it with `eval` instead of `do`.

```js
console.log((f=_=>eval(`try{-~f()}catch(e){}`))())
```

---

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) port, 24 bytes

It's not really worth posting this as a separate solution as it's, essentially, identical.

```js
Ox`try\{-~rp()}¯t®(e)\{}
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T3hgdHJ5XHstfnJwKCl9r3SuKGUpXHt9&input=)

---

### Explanation

JavaScript itself doesn't have a recursion limit per se, rather the limit is imposed by the interpreter (i.e., the browser) - good thing we define languages by their interpreter 'round here! Among other factors, the limit can vary by browser and available memory, which is impacted by the operations being performed. The following Snippet illustrates that last point, using the 5 different versions of this solution I went through. As you can see from the last 2 tests, in Chrome, at least, even the order of operations can make a difference.

```js
console.log((f=(i=0)=>eval(`try{f(i+1)}catch(e){i}`))())
console.log((f=i=>eval(`try{f(-~i)}catch(e){i}`))())
console.log((f=(i=0)=>eval(`try{f(++i)}catch(e){i}`))())
console.log((f=_=>eval(`try{-~f()}catch(e){}`))())
console.log((f=_=>eval(`try{f()+1}catch(e){0}`))())
console.log((f=_=>eval(`try{1+f()}catch(e){0}`))())
```

Given that, we therefore don't have the convenience of a constant or method to work with. Instead, we're going to create a function that calls itself continuously before, eventually, crapping out. In it's simplest form that is:

```js
f=_=>f()
```

But that's not much use to us for this challenge as it only throws an overflow error with no indication of how many times `f` called itself. We can avoid the error by *`try`ing* to call `f` continuously and `catch`ing when it fails:

```js
f=_=>{try{f()}catch(e){}}
```

No error, but still no return value of how many times the function managed to call itself before failing, because the `catch` isn't actually doing anything. Let's try evaluating the `try / catch` statement:

```js
f=_=>eval(`try{f()}catch(e){}`)
```

Now we've got a value being returned (and, because this is code golf, saved ourselves a few bytes over using an actual `return`). The value being returned, though, is `undefined`, again because the `catch` isn't doing anything. Luckily for us `-~undefined==1` and `-~n==n+1` so, by popping a `-~` in front of the call to `f`, we've essentially got `-~-~ ... -~-~undefined`, with another `-~` prepended with each call, giving us the number of times `f` was called.

```js
f=_=>eval(`try{-~f()}catch(e){}`)
```

Comment: Nice solution, since I'm assuming you don't have access to a recursion depth builtin in JS!

Comment: 33 bytes: `f=_=>eval('try{-~f()}catch(e){}')`

Comment: @Neil: I saw your 34 byte version as I was going to bed and kicked myself for not thinking of it. That 33 byte version is inspired. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

## Mathematica (no built-in), 20 bytes

```
#0[#+1];&@1
%[[1,1]]
```

Omitting the `;` will calculate `1+$IterationLimit` (probably because Mathematica tail-optimize the function). Alternatively `0 //. x_ -> x + 1` calculate `ReplaceRepeated`'s default `MaxIteration`, that is, `65536` (which is larger than both value above).

(This is a code snippet which evaluates to the result. However the other Mathematica solution is also)

Answer (score 10):

## J, 8 bytes

```
1+$: ::]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03BVk/BUFvFSsHKKpaLKzU5I18hTcHg/38A)

So, I don't actually know how to execute a verb without any input and some brief searching (as well as personal intuition) makes it seem like that isn't possible. If it is, please let me know how to do it and I'll either delete or update my answer. It doesn't really make sense for a verb to be given no input, though. In light of this, the function given expects `0`, the default "empty" input for integers. I can probably change it to use the empty array (`0$0`) if you think that's more befitting.

Edit: the OP has allowed the function to take 0.

## Explanation

```
1+$: ::]
     ::]  Assign adverse: if an error occurs, call ] (the identify function)
1+        Add one to
  $:      Recursive call to self
```

This calls itself recursively, adding 1 to the input (0 expected) until it hits a stack error. When it errors, it calls the adverse (`]`-right identity) on the input, which is just 0.

By the way, [the space is necessary](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/coco).

Comment: outputs 6000 on my machine.  fwiw i think this should be fair game, but  you can always just make your answer `(1+$: ::]) 0`

Comment: @Jonah fair point, I'm used to submitting functions. On my machine, it's 6666 oddly enough.

Comment: 6660 on an iPad pro. Cool!

Comment: The way it handles maximum recursion depth seems version dependent -- on my phone I get 5999 (which appears to be off by 1). On my iPad (honestly I don't remember which model), it just crashes.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>41</s> 32 bytes

```python
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKG4spgrzRZI6qWnlhSlJpcWFWfm5@Vk5maW/C8oyswr0UjT0NT8DwA)

Saved 9 bytes thanks to @FryAmTheEggman!

#### 34 bytes

```python
from sys import*
getrecursionlimit
```

#### 35 bytes

```python
__import__('sys').getrecursionlimit
```

The last 2 are thanks to @totallyhuman

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKG4spgLiPXSU0uKUpNLi4oz8/NyMnMzS/4XFGXmlWikaWhq/gcA "Python 3 – Try It Online"), [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehuLJYITO3IL@oRIsrPbWkKDW5tKg4Mz8vJzM3s@T/fwA "Python 3 – Try It Online") and [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Pz4@M7cgv6gkPl5DvbiyWF1TLz21pCg1ubSoODM/LyczN7Pk/38A "Python 3 – Try It Online"). Take your pick. :P

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman yes I can, thank you!

Comment: I'm getting an error (on TIO, at least) when trying to run the first 2.

Comment: @Shaggy you'll have to swap the lines for the first one, the import goes after in order to allow the builtin to be allocated a name. I'll update the link.

Answer (score 8):

## Java 8, <s>131</s> <s>51</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 43 bytes

```java
int d;int c(){try{c();}finally{return++d;}}
```

-80 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*. I tried a method instead of program as well, but made a mistake so ended up with a full program.. Now it's a method.
-3 bytes thanks to *@Neil* by making use of `finally` instead of `catch(Error e)`.
-5 byte thanks to *@Nevay* again.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##HY2xDsMgEEP3fMWNoKj5Ab6hU8aqwxVoRUouERypIsS302s92IOt5wUPvGy7p8W9u42YM1wxUO2BGJz5uVW6cjqrpGnPQBjjWZPnkmgcnWmtA@zlEYOFzMgSxxYcrIJRM6dAr9sddR1ANJ@Z/TpthaddGlbkP/9DpSfhayOrNrT@BQ)

```java
int d;                 // Depth-integer `d` on class-level (implicit 0)
int c(){               // Method without parameter and integer return-type
  try{c();}            //  Recursive call
  finally{return++d;}  //  Increase depth-integer `d` and always return it,
                       //   whether a StackOverflowError occurs or not
}                      // End of method
```

Comment: 51 bytes: `int c(){try{return-~c();}catch(Error e){return 1;}}`

Comment: @Nevay Ah, so that's what I did wrong!! I had something similar at first, but not exactly, and couldn't get it to work (hence the program instead of method).. I now also know what I did wrong.. >.>

Comment: @Nevay You often post excellent answers in comments. You could post them as answers, and get some reputations. Nothing forbids any question from having several Java answers. ;-)

Comment: `int c(){int n=1;try{n=-~c();}finally{return n;}}` saves 3 bytes but gives me a different answer?

Comment: 47 bytes: `int c(){int n=1;try{n+=c();}finally{return n;}}`

Comment: 43 bytes: `int d;int c(){try{c();}finally{return++d;}}`

Comment: @Neil "saves 3 bytes but gives me a different answer?" Java has no set max recursion depth. It all depends on several factors. One of those is memory. And `finally` is a pretty good memory eater (the code is basically duplicated. Put a `finally` in a `finally` (in the same method, not in a called method) and your code will be quadruplicated. Not saying it's actually *the* root cause, but it's a factor.

Comment: Since `int d` Is outside the function, this doesn't count as a function. To make it valid make the whole thing a lambda function like this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141334/46313

Answer (score 8):

## C (gcc, Linux x64), <s>180</s> 133 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to @scottinet*

```c
c;f(){f(++c);}h(){exit(printf("%d",c));}main(){int b[512];f(sigaction(11,(int*[]){h,[17]=1<<27},sigaltstack((int*[]){b,0,2048},0)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEER/RQrCxq6QBKVC2y8JOaSraYM1SpuDUPLtcXvxNsx7M3QeiUqh1oPYPNQ1iTZPnB/fkOCzhJg8VMd7hSSYvFyIDLk9DOaqtOXdGkZHKbwjKIXA6GSs2CY0qrG96jrdZNydOa3J0RP@yoAStbzcMkqxn5fyAw)

Installs a SIGSEGV (signal 11) handler with an alternate signal stack (minimum size `MINSIGSTKSZ` is 2 KB, flag `SA_ONSTACK` is 0x08000000), then calls a function without arguments and no local variables recursively until the stack overflows. It's interesting that the maximum recursion depth varies across runs, probably due to ASLR.

The maximum recursion depth in C depends on a lot of factors, of course. On a typical 64-bit Linux system the default stack size is 8 MB, and the stack alignment is 16 bytes, so you get a recursion depth of about 512K for simple functions.

Also note that the program above doesn't work with `-O2` because of tail call optimization.

Comment: +1! You can save 4 bytes by incrementing `c` and calling `exit` and `sigaction` as parameters. This doesn't make a noticable difference on the result: [TIO link](https://tio.run/##PY7RCoJAEEXf@woxkl3cRKUoWO1HImQcXV3atnBHCMRv37YeerrDvWdmLu4HRO@32qKZu75yerBgsvGyQakYXxRLU@RyHcPcvzWx16QtKRbvulggD8kDtA1hcKP2eizKmww3wJAjwDtL2E8b4ksrclHmh/Mqci4dTTNS9EWR9NNGUC/jKiFz0CgDg6uLqipPocMfYUUhEgjL4an3Hw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>32</s> <s>26</s> 18 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to Sven Hohenstein* : `$` will do partial matching, so we can just use `exp` instead of the full `expressions`.

```r
cat(options()$exp)
```

The `options` command can also be used to set the recursion depth, i.e., `options(expressions=500)` for 500.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCO/oCQzP69YQ1MltaJA8/9/AA)

Comment: You can save *seven* bytes by removing `ressions` due to partial matching with `$`.

Comment: More for future reference than as a contribution; is the consensus that you need to wrap this in cat()? R will output _something_ in most circumstances, so is there a post somewhere clarifying good practice/logic to follow?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein dang, I always forget about that after I write R code in good style...Thank you!

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar see for instance [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/how-should-a-full-program-in-r-be-invoked) in meta; there's certainly some uncertainty about it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>25</s> <s>22</s> 20 bytes

*2 bytes removed thanks to a suggestion by Sanchises*

```matlab
@max_recursion_depth
```

Anonymous function that outputs the value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en998hN7Eivig1ubSoODM/Lz4ltaAk43@ahuZ/AA)

Comment: You don't need the `()`, as `max_recursion_depth` is also a function.

Comment: @Sanchises Thanks! You are right: even if the doc [says](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Recursion.html) it's a variable, it's actually a function

Comment: Your edit has turned this in a duplicate of the other Octave answer, hence my retained `@` to keep it distinct (defining a function rather than REPL'ing the result).

Comment: @Sanchises Actually I just changed that, although [for a different reason](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7206/36398) (the code should actually define a function)

Comment: Yeah the other answer is more like a program; I'm not sure if that should actually require `disp` (I would have included it, but that's my personal opinion on Octave REPL, and I am not sure of any meta consensus on that)

Comment: @Sanchises Yes, I've read about that on Meta in the past and I don't think it's really settled. My opinion is like yours, I would have included `disp`

Answer (score 4):

## **Octave, 19 bytes**

```
max_recursion_depth
```

Usage:

```
octave:1> max_recursion_depth
ans =  256
```

Answer (score 3):

## zsh, 24 bytes

```
f(){f $[++i];f};set -x;f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/TUOzOk1BJVpbOzPWOq3Wuji1REG3wjrt////AA) (See under debug)

Or 12 bytes if hardcoded values are allowed (From *GammaFunction*):

```
<<<$FUNCNEST
```

## bash, 24 bytes

```
f(){ f $[++i];};set -x;f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P01Ds1ohTUElWls7M9a61ro4tURBt8I67f9/AA) (See under debug)

## ksh93, 27 bytes

```
f(){ f $(($1+1));};set -x;f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy7O@P8/TUOzWiFNQUVDQ8VQ21BT07rWuji1REG3wjrt/38A) (See under debug)

## dash, 27 bytes

```
f(){ f $(($1+1));};set -x;f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/P01Ds1ohTUFFQ0PFUNtQU9O61ro4tURBt8I67f9/AA) (Exceeds tio debug output, run it in your own shell)

Comment: Should `i=0` and the `echo` not be included in your byte count?

Comment: @Shaggy: Perhaps, I have changed it to a more self-contained solution

Comment: Zsh: `<<<$FUNCNEST` for 12 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 52 bytes

```lua
f=load"b,e=pcall(f,(...or 3)+1)return b and e or..."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxCsAgDADAub4iOCVUhNLZx8SqUAgqQd@f9taTzWYtyeDic6hpPiyCLWCMcSjcdF6kdW3tkIF7gQpD//M29e0L3dGQHNkH)

Comment: @Shaggy in this case yes, because I use the name f. If this wasn't recursive I could get away with not having it

Comment: Ah, I didn't spot the `f` in `pcall`.

Comment: why does your program stops at 200? [here](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/rTQvuSQzP08hTaNCk0tBV7egKDOvRCMlNak0Xa@kKDE5NSkxOVtDEygHkQGpAqrVNtTkSs1L4UrTMND8/x8A) you can see that in that simple function it goes beyond 200. if you remove the `--` you can confirm that it is still a recursive call with no optimizations

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{@[.z.s;x+1;x]}0
```

**Example:**

```
/ solution
q){@[.z.s;x+1;x]}0
2000

/ without apply (try/catch)
q){.z.s x+1}0
'stack
@
{.z.s x+1}
2001
```

**Explanation:**

Try to recurse, increase x by one each time, if error, return x.

```
{@[.z.s;x+1;x]}0 / the solution
{             }0 / call lambda function with 0
 @[    ;   ; ]   / @[function;argument;catch]
   .z.s          / call self (ie recurse)
        x+1      / increment x
            x    / return x if function returns error
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel-VBA, 26 Bytes

```vb
?Application.MaxIterations
```

Not recursion depth per-se, this actually outputs the maximum number of iterations for a cell in an Excel worksheet. Given that the output pertains to a language other than the language in which this is written, perhaps this is more appropriate:

## Excel + Excel-Vba, 3 + 38 = 41 Bytes

```vb
Function f:f=Application.MaxIterations
```

As that can be called from a cell with

```vb
=f(
```

For VBA with no built in:

## Excel-VBA, <s>53</s> <s>44</s> 40 bytes

-9 as variable no longer needs to be initialised or printed

-4 as code execution no longer has to be ended to avoid multiple prints

```vb
Sub s:[A1]=[A1]+1:On Error Resume Next:s
```

Call with s in the immediate window, outputs to cell A1 of the worksheet

*(warning takes a while to run now, add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` first)*

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>45</s> 37 bytes

```lua
x=2
f=load"x=x+1;f()"pcall(f)print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/wtaIK802Jz8xRanCtkLb0DpNQ1OpIDkxJ0cjTbOgKDOvRKNC8/9/AA)

I don't know which value to initialize `x` with as I don't know the number of intermediary calls there are...

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, <s>72</s> <s>55</s> 48 bytes

-23 bytes by getting rid of the atom

-7 bytes thanks to @madstap. Switched to using `fn` over `def` and `#()`, and `pr` over `println`.

```
((fn f[i](try(f(inc i))(catch Error e(pr i))))0)
```

Wrote and tested on my phone. The Clojure REPL app gave me a depth of 13087.

Basic solution. Recurse until a SO is thrown, incrementing a counter each recurse. When it's thrown, the value of the counter is printed.

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by using `pr` instead of `println`. Also -2 bytes by making the fn like this: `((fn f[x](,,,))0)` instead of `(def f #(,,,))(f 0)`.

Comment: @madstap Thanks. I'll make the changes in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, any type, <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
Function A:On Error Resume Next:A=A()+1
```

Call using `?A()` in the Immediate window, or as worksheet function.

**Note:** Returns 4613 in Excel-VBA, while the answer by @Greedo returns 3666 on my system (highest should be the max). Apparently also varies between Office programs (Access-VBA returns 4622, Word-VBA 4615)

Edit: Guess VBA auto-adds parantheses, so removed them.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 9 bytes

```
L.xyhbbyZ
```

If I can run it like the J answer above, this is 7 bytes because you can take out the last `yZ`.

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L.xyhbbyZ&debug=0).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Offline, I get a segmentation fault. Online, I get no output at all. You can't catch a segfault.

Comment: @isaacg wait this is really weird. Online, it rarely gives `764`, but you're right most of the time it gives no output.

Answer (score 0):

## Forth, 48 bytes

Loops until it hits the limit.

```
: m 1+ recurse ;
: f 0 ['] m catch drop ; f .
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WynkKhhqKxSlJpcWFacqWHNZKaQpGChEq8cCJZITS5IzFFKK8gsUrIHCev//AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 18 bytes

```
puts [interp r {}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6M68ktahAoUihujb2/38A)

`recursionlimit` can be abbreviated to `r`

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 31 bytes

```
puts [interp recursionlimit {}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6M68ktahAoSg1ubSoODM/LyczN7NEobo29v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 49 bytes

```
proc R {i\ 1} {if [catch {R [incr i]}] {puts $i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFIoTozRsGwFkilKUQnJ5YkZyhUBylEZ@YlFylkxtbGKlQXlJYUK6hk1tb@D/oPAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 39 bytes

```
END{p$.}
$stderr=$<
f=->{$.+=1;f[]}
f[]
```

Suppressing the error message is a little shorter than rescuing it, since by default `rescue` doesn't catch `SystemStackError`.

There's a cheesier answer if I can output in unary, representing `n` with n consecutive newline characters:

## Ruby, 35 bytes

```
$stderr=$<
f=->{puts;$.+=1;f[]}
f[]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

:( <sup>*</sup>

```
“¡żuẋ×HẒpƙ7"8!ƭ»ŒV
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4oCcwqHFvHXhuovDl0jhupJwxpk3Ijghxq3Cu8WSVv//)**

#### How?

* Since Jelly as far as I am aware:
(1) sets the Python recursion limit prior to setting up much of its own interpreter and parsing the code to be run; and
(2) has no way of catching Python errors
I'm not sure if there is a way to either reliably evaluate the recursion limit or to print it out as it is discovered other than to actually ask Python what the value was set to (I'd love to see if it can be done though!) so that's what the code here does:

```
“¡żuẋ×HẒpƙ7"8!ƭ»ŒV - Link: no arguments
“¡żuẋ×HẒpƙ7"8!ƭ»   - compression of "sys."+"get"+"recursion"+"limit"+"()"
                ŒV - evaluate as Python code
```