# These Days Work for Me

Tags: code-golf, date

## Background

You're an attractive code golfer and quite a few people are asking you out.

You don't have time to think about which days exactly you're available, so you decide to create a function the accepts a date and returns the days of that week.

You then take those days of the week, insert it into your calendar program to see if anyone else has asked you out already.

## Rules

- Accepts a date in YYYY-MM-DD format
- Returns an array/list of dates of that week. (Sunday is the first day)

  - The dates can be displayed as the milliseconds between January 1, 1970 and that date, in a "common" date format<sup>1</sup>, or date objects.
- The order of the dates must be ascending.

  - (Although you're smart enough to include support for a descending list, the program is able to work quickest with an ascending list and who has a few milliseconds to spare?)
- Must work with on any day since 1993. (Yes, you're 24 years old at the time of writing!)
- Every Javascript answer gets a high five!

## Specs

**Sample Input:** `whichDates(2017-08-29)`

**Output:** (the equivalent of)

```js
console.log([
  Date.parse('2017-08-27'),
  Date.parse('2017-08-28'),
  Date.parse('2017-08-29'),
  Date.parse('2017-08-30'),
  Date.parse('2017-08-31'),
  Date.parse('2017-09-01'),
  Date.parse('2017-09-02'),
]);
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> A format that is fairly well known. Such as YYYY-MM-DD.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)! Shortest code per language wins, but the shortest code overall gets the emerald checkmark!</sup>

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121176/what-week-is-it)

Comment: Also, I suggest you to allow other formats, other than `YYYY-MM-DD` (I don't see a good reason why it should be strict).

Comment: The first sentence is the weirdest and less plausible introduction I've seen in a challenge. Well done :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! But you never know who exactly is secretly admiring your sick programming skills....

Comment: Why *Every Javascript answer gets a high five!* ?

Comment: @sergiol I wanted to encourage JS, as I enjoy learning JS tricks.

Comment: `Date.parse(2017-08-27)` ?? should this be `Date.parse('2017-08-27')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 15 bytes

```
ÐU
7Æf1X+Uf -Ue
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=0FUKN8ZmMVgrVWYgLVVl&input=IjIwMTctMDgtMjkiCi1S)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of string `U`.

```
ÐU
```

Convert `U` to a date object and reassign to `U`.

```
7Æ
```

Create an array of integers from `0` to `6`, passing each through a function where `X` is the current element.

```
f1
```

Set the date of `U`.

```
X+Uf
```

Add the current date of `U` to `X`.

```
-Ue
```

Subtract the current day of the week of `U`.

Implicitly output the resulting array.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 47 bytes

```perl6
{my$d=Date.new($_);map($d+*-$d.day-of-week,^7)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/OrdSJcXWJbEkVS8vtVxDJV7TOjexQEMlRVtLVyVFLyWxUjc/Tbc8NTVbJ85cs/a/NVdxIkirhpKRgaG5roGFrpGlkiZcNC@/XNP6PwA)

The code is almost self-explanatory. First we make up a Date object `$d` from the string, which happens to be in the nice ISOwhatever format. We can perform arithmetic with the dates (adding an integer = adding that many days, the same with subtracting). So `$d-$d.day-of-week` is the <del>last</del> this (oh my god, week has always started with Monday for me :D) week's Sunday. (`.day-of-week` is 1 for Monday to 7 for Sunday.) We then map over 0 to 6 (`^7`) and add that to the Sunday, getting all the days in the week. The number we're mapping over appears in the place of the star `*`. This list is then returned.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> <s>63</s> 62 Bytes

I thought I'd also have a go at it in JavaScript.

Edit: Using the milliseconds approach, as allowed by the prompt, I reduced it down to 62 bytes.

```
s=>[..."0123456"].map(i=>(x=new Date(s))-(x.getDay()-i)*864e5)
```

You could perform a `.map(x=>new Date(x))` on the returned array if you wanted to convert it.

---

Maintaining the date approach  (**72 Bytes**)

```
s=>[..."0123456"].map(i=>new Date((x=new Date(s))-(x.getDay()-i)*864e5))
```

---

There was a bug in my initial submission, it is fixed. Thanks to an observation by milk, I was able to remove the bug and still lower the byte count.

Comment: **High Five!!**

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: It's shorter to just write out the numbers in the array. 60 bytes: `s=>[..."0123456"].map(i=>(x=new Date(s))-(x.getDay()-i)*8e7)`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and nicely tied :) Tip 1: Ditch the `keys` and use the index instead of the element when mapping over the array. Tip 2: For an array this small, it's shorter to generate it the way I did.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

I think I've finally found the environment least conducive to efficient golfing: from behind my bar, while serving pints with my other hand!

```
s=>[...""+8e6].map((_,x)=>d.setDate(d.getDate()-d.getDay()+x),d=new Date(s))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PYyxDoIwFEV/hXTqS@kLMigOZXJ0c1QjDa2kCC2hjdKvr5EQt3Nzck8v39K3s5kC95NReh6dfemYniJ5UV8RkRBW6f0dRzlR@sgXELVCr8NJBk0VdhsB3zhSYAvkSlj9yVblAVLrrHeDxsF19ElJWewOvKh4eSSwlqOoIyOZyAj7/yJgcGfXykH/9iXMxnYUAHtnbHOzDaQv) (Snippet to follow)

---

### Explanation

```
s=>
```

Anonymous function taking the string (of format `yyyy-(m)m-(d)d`) as an argument via parameter `s`.

```
[...""+8e6]
```

Create an array of 7 elements by converting `8000000` in scientific notation to a string and destructuring it, which is shorter than `[...Array(7)]`.

```
.map((_,x)=>          )
```

Map over the array, passing each element through a function where `_` is the current element, which won't be used, and `x` is the current index, 0-based.

```
,d=new Date(s)
```

Convert `s` to a `Date` object and assign it to variable `d`

```
d.setDate(     )
```

Set the date of `d`.

```
d.getDate()
```

Get the current date of `d`.

```
-d.getDay()
```

Subtract the current weekday number, 0-indexed, to get Sunday.

```
+x
```

Add `x`.

Comment: *while serving pints with my other hand!* - Nice multitasking skills :-)

Comment: Almost forgot... **High Five!**

Comment: @ChrisHappy if you're learning JS, don't look to code golf for tips :P

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Got it. I don't think I worded it well. I'm not really interested in learning how JS works, more advanced tricks with it :)

Comment: @Shaggy Could you add an explaination when you have time?

Comment: @ChrisHappy: It could well be Sunday until I have time enough to write one up; stuck behind the bar 'til then.

Comment: @ChrisHappy: Found a minute, explanation added. You should have a look at the JS tips under the [tag:tips] tag if you're looking for more trickd for golfing in JS.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
7:j8XOs21Y2=f-GYO+1XO
```

Output is in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

Try it at [**MATL Online!**](https://matl.io/?code=7%3Aj8XOs21Y2%3Df-GYO%2B1XO&inputs=2017-9-1&version=20.4.1)

#### Explanation

```
7:     % Push [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
j      % Input as a string
8XO    % Convert date to string with format 8, which is 'Mon', 'Tue' etc
s      % Sum
21Y2   % Push predefined literal [298 302 288 305 289 296 310]. The first number
       % is the sum of ASCII codes of 'Mon', the second is that of 'Tue', etc.
=      % Is equal?, element-wise
f      % Index of nonzero value. For example, if input is a Friday this gives 5
-      % Subtract, element-wise. For a Friday this gives [-4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2]
G      % Push input again
YO     % Convert to date number: number of days from January 0, 0000
+      % Add, element-wise
1XO    % Convert to date format 1, which is 'dd-mm-yyyy'. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>133</s> <s>124</s> <s>126</s> 112 bytes

<sup>-9 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder</sup>
<sup>+2 bytes because the week starts with Sunday</sup>
<sup>**-14 bytes** thanks to notjagan</sup>

```
from datetime import*
a=date(*map(int,input().split('-')))
for i in range(7):print(a-timedelta(a.weekday()-i+1))
```

That didn't go as well as I had hoped.

Comment: [127 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoMwEADvviI3dwMRaw@2B18iHhYS26WahHVL8fVpcyrMaRgmn/pM8VrKKmk3njQo78HwnpOobWiqCixwVGBckxg2HH/ktwJ2R95YoXUtIjZZajXb@VABcnXkw6YE1H1CeHk6AR3j/yIUHwFGXBYsZegvo@tvbrh/AQ)

Comment: [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYwxCsMwDAD3vMJbpIBDmg5ph7ykdBBYaUUT2ygqJa9366lw03FcPuyZ4rmURdPmAhmbbOxky0mta2iuCjqQaCC4JHXiJP7IbwPs97yKQetbRGyy1uq2mwL5ugm8GgH1H@ZXoAPQC/4fSvHBMOEdSxmH0@SHix@vXw)

Comment: [110 bytes.](https://tio.run/##FczBCoMwDIDhu0/Rm4ms4tzBbeDDBBq3MNuGmjF8@jqvPx@/7vbO6VbrUnJ0gYxNIjuJmot1Dc1ngi6SgiS7SNKvAfabrmLQ@hYRmyUXJ06SK5ReDBM@tfwxkD9fgVcjoP7H/Am0A3pBrHUcrpMf7n58HA)

Comment: This works in Python2 also if we do `raw_input()` instead of `input()` above. (+4 bytes).  `range` still works in Python2 for this small thing as well.  Without `raw_input` you get errors.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + common utilities, 53

```bash
jot -w@ 7 `date -f- +%s-%w*86400|bc` - 86400|date -f-
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Pyu/REG33EHBXCEhJbEkVUE3TVdBW7VYV7Vcy8LMxMCgJik5QUFXAcKGqfj/38jA0FzXwELXyBIA).

This assumes that the output of GNU date is a "common" date format, e.g. `Fri Sep  1 00:00:00 UTC 2017`.

#### Explanation

```bash
           date -f- +%s-%w*86400                       # read date from STDIN, output expression "seconds-since-epoch - (index of day in week * 60 * 60 * 24)
                                |bc                    # arithmetically evaluate generated expression - result is date of required sunday in seconds-since-epoch
jot -w@ 7 `                        ` - 86400           # output seconds-since-epoch for all 7 required days of the week, prefixed with "@"
                                            |date -f-  # convert all seconds-since-epoch dates back to regular dates
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 (<s>161</s> <s>154</s> <s>123</s> <s>122</s> 102 + <s>19</s> 36 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY4xa8MwEIV3/wotBanBws3iFieB0IyFDoF2CBmuytnIkSVhnQIh@Le7smv6tnvf4/hauEHuPNr2ch11511PLBCQVqxNSJLuUH44BeYAhPK5ypbRTCNpI@toFWlnJ5gpAyGwPXtkLGX5xN6dDbHDfnOkXttmx1q2HTHfPWrXc22J6W1R6U1ZHe@BsJMukvRpScZyD31AjkJ6E8MB7oHr1Sr/bxukVH7W34hXPp9fYCJy8VQKIaphTFKTio8/JqksRjenL6wDbfmf0enMoG@CWLyntBKUQk98AqfiLKoZDdkwjuvipcyL13z99gs)

```
import static java.time.LocalDate.*;

e->{for(int i=0;i<7;System.out.println(parse(e).plusDays(i++-parse(e).getDayOfWeek().getValue()%7)));}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include imports in your solution and byte count.

Comment: Also you can save bytes by removing `l` and replacing references with `LocalDate.parse(e)`.

Comment: @Jakob Good shout, thank you

Comment: And now you can increment `i` in the loop body to save 1 byte. Oh, and the `java.util.function.*` import isn't used by the lambda, so you don't have to count it as part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 20 bytes?

Mathematica expresses the list of days as a single date object.  If such date object is acceptable output, the following 20-byte pure function will work:

```
#~DateObject~"Week"&
```

**Example**

```
#~DateObject~"Week"&["2017-08-29"]
```

[image: week object]

Comment: I don't see a problem with it! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 115 Bytes or 111 Bytes, depending on input format.

Basically, this is almost the same code in [the answer for Python3 written by Sobsz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141327/4949), but made to work in Python 2.

---

#### If input is in the form `YYYY-MM-DD`:

(This assumes the input is not wrapped in single-quotes to denote a string as input)

Key difference is that we need `raw_input` instead of `input`, unless we explicitly specify the date in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` within the apostrophes to identify it as a string literal. Without the string literal input, we get a Syntax Error, hence the use of `raw_input` to accept dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` directly without putting it in string literals.

This of course assumes that the input is put in like so: `2017-08-29`.

```
from datetime import*
a=date(*map(int,raw_input().split('-')))
for i in range(7):print a-timedelta(a.weekday()-i+1)
```

+4 from Sobsz's answer, then -1 because we don't need parentheses for the `print` statement and save a byte from the closing parenthesis not being there; total of +3 bytes difference.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FcxNDoJADEDhPaeYHS06BNigJp7FNJmijcxPag3h9KNsX/K9stsrp6nWRXN0gYxNIjuJJat1Dd2PBF2kApLsrLQ9JJWvAfafsopB61tEbJasTpwkp5SeDDPeiv6BI3/8Aq9GQP3G/A60A3o5jVjrNIyzHy5@uv4A)

---

#### If input is in the form `'YYYY-MM-DD'`:

(Note that we must have the date provided inside quotes in order for this answer to work)

We get to save 4 bytes because we don't need the `raw_` and this is effectively the same answer as Sobsz provides, minus a byte because we don't need the parentheses around the `print` command.

Thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for pointing this one out, though this is **technically an exact duplicate then, minus one byte, of Sobsz's answer**.

```
from datetime import*
a=date(*map(int,input().split('-')))
for i in range(7):print a-timedelta(a.weekday()-i+1)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can replace `raw_input()` with input and surround the input with quotes to save 4 bytes. Of course, that turns your solution into a duplicate though :P

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder True, which is why I skipped that.  Though, if we put the input in quotes first, we actually *save* a byte from Sobsz, and I did make a note of that.